# Про пароли аналогичные md5

Tags: php

Господа, есть пароль, 40 знаков, выглядит так:

```
c684f43dc0c37b8d0fd58f5270929a016ead9ade
```

Известно, что это шифрованный 8-ми значный пароль. Есть ли способы определить, что это за такое, и чем это шифровалось. Напридумывали сейчас всего, и черт разберет, что это.

P.S. Это не md5, не sha.

Comment: а зачем вам это знать?

Comment: > не sha

Откуда вы знаете? По длине - как раз оно.

Comment: Это SHA1.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На самом деле это **SHA1** и зашифровано там: **1122335544**

Comment: круто) один не ленивый)) только он не восьмизначный =/ неужто коллизию нашли?))

Comment: Да, @Deonis, удовлетворите наше любопытство.

Comment: радужные таблицы?

Comment: Господа, вы поспешили ставить плюсики. На самом деле я таки ленивый )) Именно поэтому просто способом втыка нашел - http://sha1.web-max.ca/

Comment: Лень - двигатель прогресса, таки ставлю плюсик

Comment: Логично)))

---
@frank, даже не знаю, почему вы решили, что это не хеш SHA1. Если вы понимаете принцип данного алгоритма, то должны знать, что данный алгоритм хеширования возвращает 40-разрядное число в 16-ричной системе( пробежитесь-ка глазами по хешу...все буквы в пределах A-F, цифры - 0-9 ).

Comment: @Sh4dow, наверняка вы знаете, что поиск коллизий - дело нелегкое...

Comment: @Asen, именно поэтому там куча смайлов) с md5 иногда коллизию дает 5-гиговый файл, знаю)

@Deonis, ну остальные даже попробовать поленились)

Answer (score 5):

Скорее нет.

Это может быть:

```
md5($passwd).'6ead9ade';

md5(md5($passwd)).substr(0, 8, md5($passwd));

substr(0, 39, sha1($passwd)).substr(0, 1, md5($passwd));

substr(0, 20, sha1($passwd)).substr(0, 15, md5($passwd)).substr(0, 5, md5(md5($passwd).sha1($passwd.$useragent.$ip.'ololo')));
```

ну и так далее)

Comment: загадка в загадке 8-(

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов может быть туча, в плоть до приделанной "соли" к концу, или к началу md5 хэша.
А может быть (как я сам лично делаю) двойное, а то и тройное md5 хэширование и составление из разных кусочков кода.

Вариации бесконечны

Answer (score 0):

гениально, в коде будет примерно так

```
$str = '1122335544';
$str = sha1($str);
echo $str;
```

а обратно то как?

Comment: Никак, на то оно и необратимое хеширование...

Comment: Deonis дал ссылку на сайт, который это умеет, значит можно. нужно найти функцию

Comment: Тупой перебор или перебор по словарю - да, это возможно, но явно сделать что-то типа: `sha1_reverse($str)` - естественно нет.

Предоставленный сервис тупо ищет по словарю, только что попробовал довольно простой хэш - не асилил (чему не удивлен)

Comment: @mixalef, @frank, вам бы не помешало почитать это: [Криптографическая хеш-функция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)